# zoom to fit canvas by scaling to parent but provide zoom via scrollviewer

Tags: c#, wpf

**EDIT 1 19/12**

After a bit of google-fu I feel better placed to explain more concisely my problem. I wanted to implement "zoom to fit" where a canvas which is larger than it's parent is displayed with a suitable scale factor but offer the user the ability to zoom in and see the full size image (using a scroll viewer). My initial implementation did not maintain the aspect ratio of the image, instead it worked them out independently and then tried to use one slider to manage both.

I stumbled across [this tutorial](https://www.cyotek.com/blog/creating-a-scrollable-and-zoomable-image-viewer-in-csharp-part-1) to make a scrollable and zoomable image viewer which offered "zoom to fit". Following this I changed my code to the following.

```
if (CanvasWidth > CanvasHeight)
{
  ScaleX = (Math.Floor(_scrollViewer.ViewportWidth + 0.5)) / ((double)CanvasWidth);
  ScaleY = ScaleX;

  if (_scrollViewer.Height < (CanvasHeight * ScaleY) )
  {
    ScaleX = ( _scrollViewer.Height) / (CanvasHeight);
    ScaleY = ScaleX;
  }
}
else
{
   ScaleX = (Math.Floor(_scrollViewer.ViewportHeight + 0.5)) / ((double)CanvasHeight);
   ScaleY = ScaleX;

   if (_scrollViewer.Width < ( CanvasWidth * ScaleX) )
   {
      ScaleX = ((double)_scrollViewer.Width) / ((double)CanvasWidth);
      ScaleY = ScaleX;
   }
 }
```

This change seems to work perfectly but I was wondering if somebody could **explain to me how calculating the aspect ratio** like this works and scales the image to the parent control correctly?

i.e what is the significant of the "inner if statement" and how does that ensure both X and Y scale accordingly.

---

**Original Question**

I am dynamically generating content on a canvas (effectively creating an image map where each child on the canvas is clickable) where the total width/height of the content is often more than the size of it's parent. In these situations, I apply a **ScalerTransform** to scale the image to a suitable size so that it's completely visible in the parent control.

```
<Canvas.LayoutTransform>
 <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX,RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
 TemplatedParent}}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY,RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
 TemplatedParent}}" />
</Canvas.LayoutTransform>
```

Each child element on the Canvas has a constant width/height which means I can calculate the desired size of the content.

I calculate the initial X/Y scale factor by doing something like this.

```
 ScaleX = ActualCanvasWidth / DesiredCanvasWidth;
 ScaleY = ActualCanvasHeight / DesiredCanvasHeight;
```

This works as expected and results in the canvas fitting nicely in the parent container.

My problem is that I want to give the user the ability to zoom and pan around the image. To achieve this I have wrapped the Canvas inside a ScrollViewer and added a Slider.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="PART_ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<Canvas x:Name="PART_MiniMapCanvas">
    <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ScaleX,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        ScaleY="{Binding ScaleY,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
</Canvas></ScrollViewer>
```

```
<Slider TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Minimum="1" Maximum="200" Value="{Binding ScaledPercent,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" x:Name="sliderPercent" MinWidth="100px" />
```

The UI uses one slider to control the zoom and it's value is bound to a property called **ScaledPercent**. The initial value of the slider is calculated like this

```
double scaledArea = (DesiredCanvasWidth * ScaleX) * (DesiredCanvasHeight* ScaleY);
double desiredArea = DesiredCanvasWidth * DesiredCanvasHeight;
double scaledPercent = scaledArea/desiredArea;
```

It is my understanding that I can perform this calculation to find the zoom/scale percent of the whole canvas and not just the scale factor of the canvas's X/Y.

As you can [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd5lg.png), the canvas and it's parent have a height of roughly 160*200 with a desired content size of roughly 300 * 320 which equates to 48000/96000 which is where i got the 50% used by the slider.

If the user decides to zoom in and changes the value of the slider to 51, I convert this new "scaled percent" value into suitable ScaleX/Y value for the canvas. This is performed in a dependency property callback

```
 private static void OnScaledPercentChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is MiniMap map)
        {
                int newPercent = (int)e.NewValue;
                int oldPercent = (int)e.OldValue;
                int diff = newPercent - oldPercent;

                double oldWidth = map.CanvasWidth * map.ScaleX;
                double oldHeight = map.CanvasHeight * map.ScaleY;

                double scale = (diff > 0 ? (100 + diff) : (100 - Math.Abs(diff))) / 100d;

                double newHeight = scale * oldHeight;
                double newWidth = scale * oldWidth;

                map.ScaleX = newWidth / map.CanvasWidth;
                map.ScaleY = newHeight / map.CanvasHeight;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm effectively scaling the old image width/height by +/- 1% and then calculating the new scale X/Y values. This appears to be working as you can  [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6VFG.png) but if you continuously zoom in/out the canvas becomes so small it fails to show. I assume this is because I'm calculating a new width/height each time and it'll eventually round down to 0.

Clearly my implementation is over-complicated, buggy and wrong. I would appreciate it if anybody could help me or advise me how I might go about implementing my required functionality.